# Removing uninstall icons

Tags: launchpad, macos

OS X newbie here.

Many applications come with their own uninstall icons - like CS5.5, which adds *three* of them. Those are installed side-by-side with the application icons themselves.

To me, they clutter my Launchpad and program folders unnecessarily, but I can't seem to be able to remove them: dragging and dropping them to the recycle bin does nothing.

Is there a more elegant way of getting rid of these uninstall icons than placing them in a separate folder? I'm a bit anal about my launch bars and would like to avoid even that.

Can (and should) I get rid of them permanently somehow, or do they fulfill some special function that just dragging and dropping the application to the recycle bin doesn't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Adobe products, you definitely want to use the uninstaller because they place files in locations other than just the App itself, so just dragging the application to the trash won't get rid of everything. I would suggest just making a separate folder in Launchpad for uninstallers, then you can drag all of them into that folder and it will only use up one tile.